# Module robot.api not found when importing in python code

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, robotframework

I have a Python/Selenium project where I need to run code from a different file than the main one with `from ABC import XYZ`, but in the same driver (without opening a new window). From what I found, it seems that the idea is to make a singleton file, which I've done using the code from their website.

Initially, I've been getting "lib not found", which was fixed with `pip install robot`, but now I'm running into "No module named 'robot.api'" and I can't seem to find the issue. Tried `pip install robotframework-databaselibrary` but that wasn't it.

What am I missing here? FYI, my singleton.py is in the same folder as the other two .py files and my first line "from robot.api import logger" is greyed out in PyCharm.

Answer (score 4):

You have installed the wrong package - [`robot`](https://pypi.org/project/robot/#description) looks like a Django library, while you need [`robotframework`](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework/#description):

```
pip install robotframework
```

But before installing the correct one, remove the `robot` package - you'll have two with the same name, and the "wrong" probably resolves first.